# Show selected data at one time on graph plotly js, Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, plotly.js

What I want is that I have too much data in my csv file. That is to be plot on the graph using plotly js.
suppose I have 100 points on the data.
And what I want to do is that I want to plot lines using the only first 10 points.
and the other 10 in the next time till i plot 100 points.

is there any way I can achieve this in plotly js.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
<div id="ecg"  style="height: 350px"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
  function makeplot() {
    Plotly.d3.csv("out1.csv", function(data){ processData(data) } );

};

function processData(allRows) {

    console.log(allRows);
    var y = [];

    for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
        row = allRows[i];
       // x.push( row['AAPL_x'] );

        y.push( row[0]);

    }
    console.log( 'Y',y );
    makePlotly( y);
}

function makePlotly( y){
    var plotDiv = document.getElementById("plot");
    var traces = [{

        y: y
    }];

    Plotly.newPlot('ecg', traces, 
        {title: 'ECG'});
};
  makeplot();
  </script>
```

CSV data is as Follows :

```
0.09033200000000001
0.060058600000000004
0.0351562
0.0649414
0.0703125
0.0449219
0.040039099999999994
0.0649414
0.040039099999999994
0.050293
0.0649414
0.125
0.35498
0.810059
0.89502
0.549805
0.169922
-0.14502
-0.224609
-0.16503900000000002
-0.10497999999999999
-0.034668
-0.00976562
-0.0146484
0.00488281
-0.00488281
0.0102539
0.00488281
0.040039099999999994
0.015136700000000001
0.00488281
0.0
0.015136700000000001
0.00488281
0.0351562
0.030273400000000002
0.0449219
0.030273400000000002
0.0249023
0.060058600000000004
0.0952148
0.0649414
0.060058600000000004
0.10986300000000002
0.0952148
0.129883
0.149902
0.180176
0.200195
0.22998000000000002
0.245117
0.25
0.209961
0.189941
0.14013699999999998
0.11523399999999999
0.0952148
0.08007810000000001
0.055175800000000004
0.030273400000000002
0.050293
0.040039099999999994
0.015136700000000001
0.0102539
0.040039099999999994
0.0200195
0.030273400000000002
0.0703125
0.0200195
0.00488281
0.0351562
0.015136700000000001
0.0351562
0.015136700000000001
0.030273400000000002
0.040039099999999994
0.0449219
0.030273400000000002
0.040039099999999994
0.030273400000000002
0.0351562
0.0249023
0.0449219
0.0351562
0.0703125
0.050293
0.0703125
0.08007810000000001
0.050293
0.08007810000000001
0.0952148
0.10497999999999999
0.10986300000000002
0.09033200000000001
0.09033200000000001
0.08496089999999999
0.060058600000000004
0.055175800000000004
0.040039099999999994
0.09033200000000001
//just an Example
```

Comment: provide the CSV data also

Comment: @tuhin47. I updated the question with the added CSV data.

Comment: I get row[0] undefined in your code